# For loop in a function brings up random numbers

Tags: c, for-loop

So I'm writing a program about finding the sum number of all ranges for instance, if I enter a 1 and then a 10 it should display 55, but instead it display some long random number. Does anyone have a clue what's wrong with this code? Thanks!

```
#define <stdio.h>

calculateSum(int lowNumber, int highNumber);

int main()
{
   int lowerNumber,
       higherNumber;

   scanf("%d", lowerNumber);
   scanf("%d", higherNumber);

   printf("The sum of all ranges is: %d", calculateSum(lowerNumber, higherNumber));

int calculateSum(int lowNumber, int highNumber)
{
    int total;

    for(int x = lowNumber; x <= highNumber; x++)
    {
       total = total + x;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: this isn't valid C. `#define <stdio.h>` ? Shouldn't it be `#include` ? Also your main fn isn't closed before you start the next fn. Also set `total` to 0 before you use it

Comment: In `calculateSum`, You're not initializing `total`, so its initial value is random. Use `int total = 0;` to set it correctly

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing `total` before its first use as a rvalue (which is the RHS of assignment `total = total + x;`) thus its value remains undefined (and indeterminate.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@biplls answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212459/4668606) there is also another issue:

```
int lowerNumber,
   higherNumber;

scanf("%d", lowerNumber);
scanf("%d", higherNumber);
```

is UB (produces a warning on compilation and a SEGFAULT during runtime). `printf` expects an `int*`, not `int`. The correct code would be

```
int lowerNumber,
   higherNumber;

scanf("%d", &lowerNumber);
scanf("%d", &higherNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few errors here

1. it's `#include <stdio.h>` not `#define`
2. When using `scanf` you have to add an `&` before the var you read into (in this case!! )
3. The main fn doesn't return anything, it should be returning 0 (normally) (apparently I'm wrong on this , main returns 0 implicitly from C99)
4. Main fn isn't closed before you write the next fn
5. `total` should be set to 0
6. for loop initialization is allowed only in C99
7. It is a good idea to declare the return type of the prototype

fixing all this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculateSum(int lowNumber, int highNumber);

int main()
{
   int lowerNumber,
       higherNumber;

   scanf("%d", &lowerNumber);
   scanf("%d", &higherNumber);

   printf("The sum of all ranges is: %d\n", calculateSum(lowerNumber, higherNumber));
   return 0;
}

int calculateSum(int lowNumber, int highNumber)
{
    int total;
    total = 0;

    for(int x = lowNumber; x <= highNumber; x++)
    {
       total = total + x;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Running the above

```
$ ./sum
1
10
The sum of all ranges is: 55
```

Comment: compiled with `gcc -std=c99 sumc -o sum.o`

Comment: 3. is wrong, `main` has had an implicit `return 0` since C99.

Comment: I see, i didn't know that, fixed it :)